# What is the recommended approach when dealing with irregularly shaped tiles in L.TileLayer (leaflet)?

Tags: reactjs, leaflet

I am currently working on a Plan Viewer for 2D plans in a react web-app. Once a plan is uploaded to our servers in pdf format, the creation of tiles at different zoom levels is triggered.
Now I want to leverage leaflet to display the plan tiles in our web-app.

My problem is that the 'l.TileLayer' from Leaflet assumes that all tiles are shaped the same (could be square or not). I do not want to change the tile creation flow as our mobile app uses the current tile format and I do no want to break the existing features in the mobile app.

To give more context:

Let's say the example plan is 7000 x 4000 pixels after the pdf has been rendered at 300 DPI. Now we want to create tiles of 512x512 pixels.

To cover the whole plan with the tiles, we need 14 x 8 tiles. As 14 x 512 > 7000 and 8 x 512 > 4000, the tiles on the right and the bottom will be cut off.

Another problem we would have here is the fact that the number of tiles does not multiply exactly by 2 with each zoom level (as assumed by leaflet).

The number of tiles per zoom level would be
14 x 8
7 x 4
4 x 2
2 x 1
1 x 1 (minimum zoom level: One tile covers the whole plan)

I tried using the 'l.TileLayer' with a 'l.CRS.Simple' coordinates system (as it is a 2D plan), but it did not work as I was hoping as the assumptions are not fulfilled.
[https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#gridlayer:~:text=inherited%20from%20Evented-,TileLayer,-Used%20to%20load](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#gridlayer:%7E:text=inherited%20from%20Evented-,TileLayer,-Used%20to%20load)
[https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#gridlayer:~:text=the%20include%20function.-,L.CRS.Simple,-A%20simple%20CRS](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#gridlayer:%7E:text=the%20include%20function.-,L.CRS.Simple,-A%20simple%20CRS)

I was wondering if using the 'l.GridLayer', which provides more customisation possibilities, could help me in this case: [https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#gridlayer:~:text=into%20GeoJSON%20features.-,GridLayer,-Generic%20class%20for](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#gridlayer:%7E:text=into%20GeoJSON%20features.-,GridLayer,-Generic%20class%20for)

Comment: Pad your image with transparent (or black) pixels to make its size a multiple of 256px.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem by defining a custom GridLayer like this:

```
const TilesGridLayer = GridLayer.extend({
createTile: function (coords: {x: number; y: number; z: number}) {
  const tile = document.createElement('div');
  tile.style.width = tile.style.height = `${tileSize}px`;
  const img = new Image();
  img.src = tileUrlPattern
    .replace('(z)', coords.z.toString())
    .replace('(r)', coords.y.toString())
    .replace('(c)', coords.x.toString());
  tile.appendChild(img);
  return tile;
}, }) as new (options?: GridLayerOptions) => GridLayer;
```